# Computing a move score in a Minimax Tree of a certain depth

Tags: c, algorithm, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I've implemented a Chess game in C, with the following structs:

> move - which represents a move from (a,b) to (c,d) on a char board[8][8] (Chess board)
>
> moves - which is a linked list of moves with head and tail.
>
> **Variables:**
> playing_color is 'W' or 'B'.
> minimax_depth is a minimax depth that was set before.

Here is my code of the Minimax function with alpha-beta pruning and the getMoveScore function which should return the score of the move in Minimax Tree of a certain minimax_depth that was set before.

As well I'm using the getBestMoves function which I will also list here, it basicly find the best moves during the Minimax algorithm and saves them into a global variable so that I will be able to use them later.

I must add that all the functions that are listed within the three functions that I will add here are working properly and were tested, *so the problem is either a logic problem of the alphabetaMax algorithm or the implementation of
getBestMoves/getMoveScore.*

**The problem mainly is that when I get my best moves at depth N (which are also not computed right somewhy) and then check their score on the same depth with getMoveScore function, I'm getting different scores that don't match the score of those actual best moves**. I've spent hours on debugging this and couldn't see the error, I hope maybe anyone could give me a tip on finding the problem.

***Here is the code:***

```
/*
* Getting best possible moves for the playing color with the minimax algorithm
*/
moves* getBestMoves(char playing_color){
    //Allocate memory for the best_moves which is a global variable to fill it in   a minimax algorithm//
    best_moves = calloc(1, sizeof(moves));
    //Call an alpha-beta pruned minimax to compute the best moves//
    alphabeta(playing_color, board, minimax_depth, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, 1);
    return best_moves;
}

/*
* Getting the score of a given move for a current player
*/
int getMoveScore(char playing_color, move* curr_move){
    //Allocate memory for best_moves although its not used so its just freed    later//
    best_moves = calloc(1, sizeof(moves));
    int score;
    char board_cpy[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    //Copying a a current board and making a move on that board which score I   want to compute//
    boardCopy(board, board_cpy);
    actualBoardUpdate(curr_move, board_cpy, playing_color);
    //Calling the alphabeta Minimax now with the opposite color , a board after     a given move and as a minimizing player, because basicly I made my move so  its now the opponents turn and he is the minimizing player//
    score = alphabeta(OppositeColor(playing_color), board_cpy, minimax_depth, INT_MIN, INT_MAX, 0);
    freeMoves(best_moves->head);
    free(best_moves);
    return score;
}

/*
* Minimax function - finding the score of the best move possible from the input board
*/
int alphabeta(char playing_color, char curr_board[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE], int depth,int alpha,int beta, int maximizing) {
    if (depth == 0){
        //If I'm at depth 0 I'm evaluating the current board with my scoring            function//
        return scoringFunc(curr_board, playing_color);
    }
    int score;
    int max_score;
    char board_cpy[BOARD_SIZE][BOARD_SIZE];
    //I'm getting all the possible legal moves for the playing color//
    moves * all_moves = getMoves(playing_color, curr_board);
    move* curr_move = all_moves->head;
    //If its terminating move I'm evaluating board as well, its separate from depth == 0 because    only here I want to free memory//
    if (curr_move == NULL){
        free(all_moves);
        return scoringFunc(curr_board,playing_color);
    }
    //If maximizing player is playing//
    if (maximizing) {
        score = INT_MIN;
        max_score = score;
        while (curr_move != NULL){
            //Make the move and call alphabeta with the current board               after the move for opposite color and !maximizing player//
            boardCopy(curr_board, board_cpy);
            actualBoardUpdate(curr_move, board_cpy, playing_color);
            score = alphabeta(OppositeColor(playing_color), board_cpy, depth - 1,alpha,beta, !maximizing);
            
            alpha = MAX(alpha, score);
            if (beta <= alpha){
                break;
            }
            //If I'm at the maximum depth I want to get current player              best moves//
            if (depth == minimax_depth){
                move* best_move;
                //If I found a move with a score that is bigger then                    the max score, I will free all previous moves and                   append him, and update the max_score//
                if (score > max_score){
                    max_score = score;
                    freeMoves(best_moves->head);
                    free(best_moves);
                    best_moves = calloc(1, sizeof(moves));
                    best_move = copyMove(curr_move);
                    concatMoves(best_moves, best_move);
                }
                //If I have found a move with the same score and want                   to concatenate it to a list of best moves//
                else if (score == max_score){
                    best_move = copyMove(curr_move);
                    concatMoves(best_moves, best_move);
                }
                
            }
            //Move to the next move//
            curr_move = curr_move->next;
        }
        freeMoves(all_moves->head);
        free(all_moves);
        return alpha;
    }
    else {
        //The same as maximizing just for a minimizing player and I dont want       to look for best moves here because I dont want to minimize my          outcome//
        score = INT_MAX;
        while (curr_move != NULL){
            boardCopy(curr_board, board_cpy);
            actualBoardUpdate(curr_move, board_cpy, playing_color);
            score = alphabeta(OppositeColor(playing_color), board_cpy, depth - 1,alpha,beta, !maximizing);
            beta = MIN(beta, score);
            if (beta <= alpha){
                break;
            }
            curr_move = curr_move->next;
        }
        freeMoves(all_moves->head);
        free(all_moves);
        return beta;
    }
}
```

As Eugene has pointed out-I'm adding an example here:
http://imageshack.com/a/img910/4643/fmQvlm.png

I'm currently the white player, i got only king-k and queen-q, the opposite color has king-K and rook-R. Obviously my best move here is to eat a rook or cause a check at least. Moves of the pieces are tested and they work fine. Although when i call get_best_moves function at depth 3, I'm getting lots of unnecessary moves and negative scores for them at that depth. Maybe now it's a little more clear. Thanks!

Comment: No MCVE, no expected behavior, no actual behaviour. We have a little to do with this.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I added a detailed example now, should I add anything else?

Comment: @EvgenyA.: Tossed you a +1 for constructive collaboration elsewhere. You need it more than I do. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without debugging your whole code, at least ONE of the problems is the fact that your scoreverification might work with a minimax algorithm, but not with a Alpha-Beta. Following problem:

The getMoveScore() function has to start with an open AB Window.

The getBestMoves() however call getMoveScore() with an already closed AB Window.

So in the case of getBestMoves, there can be branches pruned that are not being pruned in getMoveScore(), therefore the score not being exact, and thats the reason (or at least ONE of them) why these valued can differ.

Comment: I don't quite understand what do you mean by closed AB Window, you mean that I should call the function alphabeta in getMoveScore with OppositeColor but as a maximizing player? As I understand this, in getMoveScore I make a move, so I should call alphabeta for the opponent but should he minimize or maximize?

Comment: AB Window has nothing to do with min or max. An Alpha Beta Window is for example -300 +100, representing your alpha and beta values. Due to cutoffs, different Alpha or Beta values often result in different move values.

Comment: Alright I understand, and what do you mean by open AB Window? What values should I try? Or how can I compute what values I need? By the way, getBestMoves doesn't call getMoveScore, they are independent.

Comment: @Evgeny If you want the sane outputs from the two, you will need to either store your alpha beta values you used for the specific score, or switch off the alpha beta pruning. Anyway, I have no clue why you would want to do such a check...

Comment: Okey thank you , i'll take that in mind. I'm just studying CS, and it's a project in one of our courses.

Comment: Do you also have any clue why the best moves are not computed right?

Comment: Not yet... I'll have another look at it.